# What is the performance penalty of using RansomWhere.app?

Tags: malware

As many might be aware OS X is now potential victim of ransomware exploits.  So far we have one example only, [First Mac-targeting ransom ware hits Transmission users, researchers say](http://arstechnica.com/security/2016/03/first-mac-targeting-ransomware-hits-transmission-users-researchers-say/), but chances are that these exploits will increase.

I recently read about [RansomWhere.app](https://objective-see.com/products/ransomwhere.html) that might be effective in protecting your mac from ransom ware attacks, by monitoring the file system for the creation of encrypted files (and blocking the process doing the encryption).  My understanding is that the developer(s) of this program are highly qualified and whatnot but (and here is the questions):

Does anyone use this program?  What is the performance penalty?

I ask because I have multiple redundant backups, so a ransom ware attack would force me to wipe my disk and use one of my backups (losing a day or less of files at most)?  Multiple redundant backups are needed anyway, so what is the *net* advantage of using ransomware defeating software?

Comment: It would help to give the names of those links - I would not click on the first one without what is there being fully explained first

Comment: @Mark, One can usually see the URL's in the Status Bar of a Browser, so IMO it's not that big of a deal if the hyperlinks aren't thoroughly descriptive and you could have edited them too.

Comment: I wouldn't. So long as you don't visit fishy sites, don't install unverified software, etc. you really should be fine. But hey, it could save the day. Keep  in mind that that app could be just another vector for a ransomware attack...

Answer (score 2):

I have used it for the past few weeks on my 12" Retina MacBook and noticed no impact on performance.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/164880)

Comment: @Allan Sounds like it answers the question to me, even if just anecdotally.

Comment: As the person who asked the question I feel this is a valid answer (which I upvoted).  I'd like to have a quantification if at all possible though.